# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named python

Tags: python

I got an error. I created a module and it recognize it everywhere but did not work when i trined to import it in seedlingsWidget.py . I tried some solutions but nothing worked.
I tried to add **init**.py in every directory.
I tried to add the path of the directory to `sys.path.append`

[image]

[image]

```
from models.seedlings import Seedlings
```

how can I fix that?
I will be happy for some help, thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please, show classes within `seedlings.py` and `seedlingType.py`. Based on your screenshots, you are importing from seedlingType, but from the code you provide you use `from models.seedlings ...`

Plus, which file you trying to run? (in order to understand relative import)

Comment: hey, thank you simon. it tring to that:  import from seedlingType import SeedlingType
from helper import MAX_SEEDLINGS_TYPES in seedlings.py and in seedlingType i not importing.  i trying to run mainWindow.py there is my main window gui

Comment: When you run `mainWindow.py`, he looks for the same level. You do not have `seedlings.py` or`seedlingsType.py` on the same level. In `mainWindow.py` you should have something like `from models.seelings import ...` or `from models.seedlingType import ...`

Comment: even if i am not use the module their??, because it tried to add the imports their and its still not working

Comment: @IL994 Can't help you without the actual code, not just the names of the files

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
from models.seedlingsType import SeedlingsType
```

Comment: File "/Users/blablabla/Desktop/work/python/Farm Area Excercise/models/seedlings.py", line 1, in <module>
    from seedlingType import SeedlingType
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seedlingType'

Comment: its show that the problem is in seedlings.py but its worked before i add the module in seedlingsWidget.py